# JFrame doesn't appear with ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, actionlistener

I'm a beginner and I've written this code but it does not seem to work. I've  run the code and for some reasons the `JFrame` does not appear (the class name is in Hungarian, do not mind it).

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class főMásolgató implements ActionListener {

    JButton b;
    JLabel label;
    JTextField tfield;
    JFrame frame;

    public void főMásolgató(){
        frame = new JFrame();
        b = new JButton("Másolás");
        label = new JLabel("");
        tfield = new JTextField();
        frame.add(b);
        frame.add(label);
        frame.add(tfield);
        b.addActionListener(this);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        label.setText(tfield.getText());
    }
}

public class másolgatóHasználata {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        new főMásolgató();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The void method főMásolgató is not the class constructor.

When you instance a new főMásolgató you're simply invoking the default no-args constructor instead of the void method főMásolgató where you show your `JFrame`.

You should re-write it like this:

```
public class főMásolgató implements ActionListener {

    JButton b;
    JLabel label;
    JTextField tfield;
    JFrame frame;

    //This is now YOUR no-args constructor not the default one provided by Java
    public főMásolgató(){
        frame = new JFrame();
        b = new JButton("Másolás");
        label = new JLabel("");
        tfield = new JTextField();
        frame.add(b);
        frame.add(label);
        frame.add(tfield);
        b.addActionListener(this);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        label.setText(tfield.getText());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is that

```
public void főMásolgató(){ ... }
```

is a **function** not a constructor.

Your code will work if you do:

```
public class másolgatóHasználata {
  public static void main(String args[]){
    new főMásolgató().főMásolgató();
  }}
```

because here he will use the default constructor. then he will call your function.
Or you can fix it by changing:

```
public void főMásolgató(){ ... }
```

to

```
public főMásolgató(){ ... }
```

Then your block is the **constructor**.

***Hint:*** you can debug this by running line by line. This will let you know if your block was run or not.